# relative Path for Ipad Project

Tags: ipad, relative-path

I know that this is a stupip question, but i cannot find out what my relative Path is... :(

I have an iPad Project and under this a folder for Images

[image]

I want to set an UIImage, but i cannot figure out what my relative path is--

I tried this:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Images/send.png"];
```

But it is not working....

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to find the relative path, if your image is present in your bundle. However `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]` will give the relative path of your bundle.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"send.png"];
```

This is basic method for loading the image.

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"send.png"];
```

This will load the images faster. Because it load the image without cache.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"send"];
```

Use this if you want to use the image for both ordinary and retina screens. In your bundle you should have two images "send.png" and "send@2x.png" where "send@2x.png" is twice as the size of "send.png".